# onblur functionality stops working in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I have a simple function that checks a field is a number, and that it begins "000".
This is checked using "onblur", to provide instant(ish) feedback to the user.

My code:

```
function IsNumeric(input)
{
return (input - 0) == input && (''+input).trim().length > 0;
}

function checkNumber(field) {
if (!IsNumeric(field.value)) {
seterrorlabel("That's not a number");
toggleButton('SubmitButton', true);
} else if (!(field.value.substring(0, 3) == "000")) {
seterrorlabel("All numbers must begin 000. One 0 for external. Two 0's for an international number.");
toggleButton('SubmitButton', true);
} else {
toggleButton('SubmitButton', false);
seterrorlabel("");
}
}

function toggleButton(button,disableit) {
var input = document.getElementById(button);
input.disabled = disableit;
}

function seterrorlabel(message) {
var thelabel = document.getElementById('numbererror');
thelabel.innerHTML = message;
}
```

The problem is that in Internet Explorer 11, the onblur function appears to work only once. I can enter a number such as "001234" and receive the expected error, but after correcting the error, and entering a valid "0001234" the label is not cleared.
Similarly, if i add letters, to make this non-numeric, the label does not update.
In Chrome, this works pefectly however, and it updates each time i would expect onblue to fire.

Any ideas?

Comment: What about a fiddle? Worst case you can reattach you onblur() handler from `checkNumber()'...

Comment: @sb9 - [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r1LLc8h0) - Which for some reason doesn't seem to work at all now.

Comment: I updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r1LLc8h0/2/), and it works in Chrome as well as in IE11...

Comment: So, your fiddle works. When copy/pasted into my test page however, it breaks. However! I do now get this error:  Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'trim'. It points to the isNumeric function. How could this be? It is passing a string of value "000". Something screwy in IE?

Comment: It seems that there's a type mismatch for the parameter of `IsNumeric()`, it seems to be number, not string, and number has no method `trim()`. You should usr `parseInt()`where you expect a number, and `String()` where you expect a string.

Comment: BTW, the only thing I changed in the fiddle was to make your javascript function callable within JSFiddle, there's no need to perform that change in a real application...

Comment: @sb9 Thanks for the info! I assumed it wouldn't matter, since the IsNumeric function was not my own, but it turns out it really does.
Instead, i ended up replacing that function with something that is apparently from jquery 1.7, and now works beautifully. New function is: `function IsNumeric(n) { 
      return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n); 
}`
From [here](http://www.neiland.net/blog/article/javascript-isnumeric/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed in Internet Explorer by using a different function for IsNumeric - the previous one was causing issues, though they were not showing the console until changing the function definition to global scope.

Answer (score 0):

just want to confirm that when you enter '001234' and hit the button, does your button gets enabled when focus again to the textbox

Comment: In Chrome, as long as the input is "valid" the button is enabled. As long as the input is "invalid" the button remains disabled. In Internet Explorer, i've not been able to test properly, due to this issue.

Comment: you should add onfocus event and a function like:
<input type="text" name="fname" id='xyz' onfocus="enableButton()">

function enableButton(){
toggleButton('SubmitButton', false);
}

Comment: This will enable the Submit button and makes the functionality working.